# laravel 4 custom validation for multiple store

Tags: php, validation, laravel-4

I have `user` table, and there is email and username field which is not unique. Because i am working with multi store site. So every store have its own user. for example

`www.myex.com/store1` has user `test123` and it has `store_id=1` and `www.myex/com/store2` has same user `test123` and it has `store_id=2` in database.

Now, when user register, if user 'test123' want to register in store `store2`
then validation should work like this

```
if(username exist && it_has_store==2 )
  echo 'already exist';
```

Right now i am using this

```
$validator = Validator::make($input, array(
        'username' => 'required',
        'password' => 'min:7|required|confirmed'
    ));
```

But not filling my requirement, how can we achieve this in `laravel`?